# Is it possible to avoid "pending for revision" stage on Google Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a couple of months using Google Chrome Web Developer dashboard. Everything was very normal, publishing an updated version was taking around 30-40 mins, now that I added a few elements to my extension such as popmotion.js it keeps requiring manual revisions and my extension gets into "Pending for Review" state for so long.

My question is: Is this caused by something I could have done in the code? Is it possible to get rid of this condition that keeps telling Google's services that my extension needs to be manually reviewed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's quite likely something in your code caused this but we can't tell without seeing it.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm... There are major changes in this version and it's going to be too much code to share here. My question is: -based on your experience- what should I look for? What are the kind of things that may trigger a manual review?

Comment: Changes in permissions, content scripts, their `matches`, loading/injecting of externally hosted code, eval(), new Function().

Comment: Well... that's basically all I could  change in a Chrome Extension... I´m going to start discarding permissions, externally hosted code and eval... There are new matches and new functions but I would consider this a normal event in an application life cycle. I'm still confused on how's that considered by Google as terms and conditions infringement or anything.

Comment: There are extensions that use eval or a function constructor and external code to run arbitrary unchecked code in the browser. In most cases an extension can and should manage without any of those or put the risky code inside a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: They are likely doing long reviews on purpose in some cases to discourage developers from making frequent updates. Just changing description/information about the extension without editing the package can trigger a >week review.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-08), Pending review means the Chrome Web Store automated systems have flagged your item for manual review.

Some of the reasons an item could be flagged for manual review include:

- The item may have an NPAPI plugin, which requires a signed agreement from you. Check your email account associated with the item for an agreement notification from our abuse team.
- The item is suspected to contain or to be distributed by malware or unwanted software.
- The item is suspected to violate one of the developer program policies.
- The item may have already been previously removed for a legal or policy violation, and has been resubmitted.
- The item requests powerful permissions that require in-depth review.